# iPadOS Add entry to text replacement (user dictionary) from shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, dictionary, ipados, shortcuts-app

I’m using the apple pencil on Ipad and work with a lot of abbreviations. So every-time I write one, it will be replaced with whatever is the closest match in the English dictionary. I can work around that by adding the abbreviations in the user dictionary (settings - general - keyboard - text replacement).
So I often find myself going to this setting to add a new abbreviation.
I would like to make this a bit easier by creating a shortcut that can do it for me. So far, all I can do is a shortcut that will take me to the “text replacement” page :

```
prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/USER_DICTIONARY
```

It’s ok but I wish I could just ask for input and push this into the user dictionary all through the shortcut.

Is there a way to do this?